# How to call CountDown timer from ViewModel class

Tags: timer, dispatcher

I am testing how Dispatcher CountDown timer works in my MVVM model project. It works only when I call from constructor method. There is other method that i want to call and start timer based on the value of the variable. Like when the call is disconnected being watched in a method and soon the call is disconnected then I want to start timer, uisng WPF UserControl.

```
        private void startTimer()
        {
            DispatcherTimer dtimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            dtimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            dtimer.Tick += dtTicker;
            dtimer.Start();
        }
```

```
        private void dtTicker(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            increment++;
            TBCountDown = increment.ToString();
        }
```

```
      <Label x:Name="label1" Content="{Binding TBCountDown}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,212,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.101,0.605" Width="58" Height="29"/>
```

I tried but doesn't work the way it should be.